# How to produce a full date given the year in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a big data set of dates.
For simplicity, suppose I have,

```
dates<-c("2006","2009-10-19","2008-11-08","2002-07")
```

Where the standard format is

```
"YYYY-MM-DD"
```

My question is, how would I go about adding the month and day so that all dates are in standard form so that the vector becomes:

```
dates<-c("2006-01-01","2009-10-19","2008-11-08","2002-07-01")
```

Essentially, for all non-standard date forms, I want to add "01" to the missing entry.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ymd` with `truncated`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(dates, truncated = 2)
```

-output

```
[1] "2006-01-01" "2009-10-19" "2008-11-08" "2002-07-01"
```